# Best suited PrC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class

I'm creating a Direlock and am thinking of going for a PrC, Could someone tell me some suggestions that would be best suited to a Direlock? I'm thinking of doing Shadowdancer, but I'd like others opinions.